# tap gesture on containing view blocks tableView selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
            [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(id)handleSingleTap {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

I have a view that contains a tableview, and I want to end editing on textfields when the view is tapped. However, I do not want this to prevent selection of contained elements. Specifically, I have a tableview whose cells cannot be selected unless I swipe them. A single tap gets swallowed by the gesture recognizer and doesn't go through.

If I remove the gesture recognizer, the table works fine.

How can I handle tap events on the view and not prevent subviews from receiving the events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your class as the delegate of your `UITapGestureRecognizer` and implement the method 
`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` and then check the `UITouch` location, if is on the `tableView` then return NO, if not return YES.

For `UITouch` location use [locationInView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITouch): method